# How to generate a random 5 letter code and give filters

Tags: javascript, random

I want to generate a random 5 letter code and give filters that the code will not same to the filters. I also want filters to be in an array. If there are too many filters that the code can't generated, it will make new character in the code. Like in [YouTube](https://youtube.com), in a video, a random letter of 9 characters is generated and it has given filters to not generate the same.
The generation function and the filter generate function (90%) are created but only one problem is written in the code:

```js
var l = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz${"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toUpperCase()}0123456789`;

function generateCode(c) {
  var t = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    t += l.split("")[randomNumber(0, l.length)];
  }
  return t;
}
function filtersPreventGenerate(generated, minCharacters) {
  /*
  generated: array
  minCharacters: number
  */
  var t = "";
  var characters = minCharacters;
  t = generateCode(characters);
  while (generated.indexOf(t) > -1) {
    t = generateCode(c);
    // i can't tell what is the code to check there are too many items in the generated argument that 5 letter can't generated. what will be the code?
  }
  return t;
}
function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: you mean once there are too many codes to make more unique codes, it will start making 6-letter codes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Driftr95 yes, how it will be done?

Comment: set a `maxCodes` variable and increase characters if it's exceeded like `if (generated.length >= maxCodes) {minCharacters ++;}` [`minCharacters` should be a global variable rather than a parameter for this]. the maximum combinations would be *allowabeChars^codeLength* so like `maxCodes = Math.pow(l.length, characters)` here, but you can set it to something lower (by dividing etc) if you don't want to generate all possible combinations (it might get slower when `generated.length` starts getting closer to `max` because the `while` will loop more)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet that you can use as a 5-letter code generator

```
function generate(len = 5){
    let charset = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM!@#$%^&*()"
    let result = ""
for(let i = 0; i<len;i++ ){
    let charsetlength = charset.length
result+=charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charsetlength))
}
return result;
}
```

And below snippet is responsible to assign the random as a "code" variable, based on it you can create filter inside the function

```
$(document).on("click", ".generate", function(){
    let code = generate()
    // your filters here
})
```

Comment: but i want the filters function (set filters to like "dbdw3", "degc6", "mf2xA", "fWs3k")